# Upgrade Expired SQL Server 2008R2 Evaluation to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

We have been working on developing several SharePoint sites as a POC using the evaluation versions of SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise Evaluation. POC worked, went into limited production, well the SQL Server Evaluation expiration date snuck up on me and expired, so it's time to purchase ASAP.

Ideally because of the new price models, I want to use SQL Server 2012 Standard, licensed by processor.

Now the question is, can I do a in place upgrade from the expired SQL 2008R2 trial directly to SQL 2012 Standard?

Or better yet, export the sharepoint databases from the expired trial, so I can import them into a brand new SQL 2012 installation.

Comment: 1. Backup database(s) on old server. 2. Restore database(s) on new server. 3. Done.

Comment: cant open SQL Management studio on an expired license

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to attach the database files directly to your 2012 instance. Please read the section on attach here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30440/how-do-i-attach-a-database-in-sql-server